# How to create dynamic tableView sections in swift3?

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift3

I'm working on complete dynamic form in swift3, how to create multiple dynamic sections based on JSON service response array count. 
And each section having different elements.

For example:
 JSON response array count 3.
 Each index having different elements, based on index section to implement 
 tableview sections.

Example Data:

```
[
    [
    "action-note",
    "actions-control",
    confirm,
    confirm
],
    [
    "select-conditional",
    select,
    select,
    "action-note",
    "actions-control",
    confirm,
    confirm,
    confirm
],
    [
    "tab-control",
    "action-note",
    "error-text",
    checkbox,
    "actions-control"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a stab at what I think you are asking... You want to know how to make a tableview... (UITableview) that looks something like below... but be able to have more or less sections and more or less rows per section based on your returned JSON.

```
Section 1
  action-note
  actions-control
  confirm
  confirm

Section 2
  select-conditional
  select
  select
  action-note
  actions-control
  confirm
  confirm
  confirm

Section 3
  tab-control
  action-note
  error-text
  checkbox
  actions-control
```

First, you need to place your JSON stuff into an array of arrays ([ [ ] ]).

```
'[[Section name1, row1, row2, row3, row...n],
  [Section name2, row1, row2, row3, row...n],
  [Section name3, row1, row2, row3, row...n]]'
```

The UITableview code will look like below...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource  {


let arrOfArrFromJSON= '[["Section 1", "action-note", "actions-control", "confirm", "confirm"],
  ["Section 2", "select-conditional", row2, row3, row...n],
  [Section name3, row1, row2, row3, row...n]]' //Blah blah you can fill the rest of the array out
let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell" //This is your cell identifier that was defined on the storyboard.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
 // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections

    return arrOfArrFromJSON.count //Counting the number of arrays within your array. Or number of sections within your array.

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrOfArrFromJSON[section].count //For each section, it counts the number of rows.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell! //Your UITableView is called 'tableView' in this example. It could be whatever you defined it as in the storyboard.

    cell.textLabel?.text = arrOfArrFromJSON[indexPath.section][indexPath.row+1] // This will name each row or cell label according to whats in your array of arrays. The +1 is to not start at your section name.

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row) within section number \(indexPath.section)")//When you click on a cell it will return what cell you pressed in what section.
}

}
```

I did not test this code so it may have some syntax errors. This should get you close though.